# Weighted random sampler - oversample or undersample?

Tags: pytorch, oversampling, pytorch-dataloader

### Problem

I am training a deep learning model in PyTorch for binary classification, and I have a dataset containing unbalanced class proportions. My minority class makes up about `10%` of the given observations. To avoid the model learning to just predict the majority class, I want to use the `WeightedRandomSampler` from `torch.utils.data` in my `DataLoader`.

Let's say I have `1000` observations (`900` in class `0`, `100` in class `1`), and a batch size of `100` for my dataloader.

Without weighted random sampling, I would expect each training epoch to consist of 10 batches.

### Questions

- Will only 10 batches be sampled per epoch when using this sampler - and consequently, would the model 'miss' a large portion of the majority class during each epoch, since the minority class is now overrepresented in the training batches?
- Will using the sampler result in more than 10 batches being sampled per epoch (meaning the same minority class observations may appear many times, and also that training would slow down)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch - how to undersample using weightedrandomsampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320232/pytorch-how-to-undersample-using-weightedrandomsampler)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878940/how-to-create-a-balancing-cycling-iterator-in-pytourch

Answer (score 4):

A small snippet of code to use `WeightedRandomSampler`
First, define the function:

```
def make_weights_for_balanced_classes(images, nclasses):
    n_images = len(images)
    count_per_class = [0] * nclasses
    for _, image_class in images:
        count_per_class[image_class] += 1
    weight_per_class = [0.] * nclasses
    for i in range(nclasses):
        weight_per_class[i] = float(n_images) / float(count_per_class[i])
    weights = [0] * n_images
    for idx, (image, image_class) in enumerate(images):
        weights[idx] = weight_per_class[image_class]
    return weights
```

And after this, use it in the following way:

```
import torch 
dataset_train = datasets.ImageFolder(traindir)                                                                         
                                                                                
# For unbalanced dataset we create a weighted sampler                       
weights = make_weights_for_balanced_classes(dataset_train.imgs, len(dataset_train.classes))                                                                
weights = torch.DoubleTensor(weights)                                       
sampler = torch.utils.data.sampler.WeightedRandomSampler(weights, len(weights))                     
                                                                                
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle = True,                              
                                                             sampler = sampler, num_workers=args.workers, pin_memory=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're after, check [`torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler) documentation for details.

There is an argument `num_samples` which allows you to specify how many samples will actually be created when `Dataset` is combined with `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` (assuming you weighted them correctly):

- If you set it to `len(dataset)` you will get the first case
- If you set it to `1800` (in your case) you will get the second case

> Will only 10 batches be sampled per epoch when using this sampler - and consequently, would the model 'miss' a large portion of the majority class during each epoch [...]

Yes, **but** new samples will be returned after this epoch passes

> Will using the sampler result in more than 10 batches being sampled per epoch (meaning the same minority class observations may appear many times, and also that training would slow down)?

Training would not slow down, each epoch would take longer, but convergence should be approximately the same (as less epochs will be necessary due to more data in each).

Comment: "If you set it to len(dataset) you will get the first case." Meaning I will be oversampling my minority class?

Comment: @JoanaRocha yes, you would be in both cases. In the first one, you would draw 1000 samples and ~500 would be a minority (oversampled 5 times) and the majority would be ~500 (under-sampled a little bit). In the second case, you would __probably__ get 900 from the majority (not under-sampled at all) and 900 from the minority (oversampled 9 times). Multiply it by many epochs and, on average, you will see every majority sample and most minority samples multiple times.